# How to make .bundle file executable?

Tags: ios, executable, target

I am creating a resource bundle which contains all .xib and images. When I am loading this bundle by resourceAtPath: method which propmt a message that bundle is not yet loaded. Reason for this is that bundle's executables are not located. As in application bundle executable file is memdatory. To make it executable I am adding simple a utility.h amd .m file which do nothing simple having nslog message to make bundle loaded successfully. 
Is this approch is right or not?
Is APPLE reject my app which is using such resouce bundle having dummy executable?
Please help me.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps are forbidden to load external executables. You need to static link your code and just use the bundle(s) for resources.